# Remove button pane at the bottom in NSIS installer

Tags: nsis

I'm using NSIS to create an installer which will only have custom pages.
The custom page shouldn't have the default buttons (back, next or cancel), but only 1 button in the center of the page.
Is there any way I can remove the full bottom pane, as I have highlighted in the image attached ?
I have hid the buttons, but I would like to remove the separator line and the section below it as well.

This is code I have:

```
;--------------------------------
;Include Modern UI
  !include "MUI2.nsh"

;--------------------------------
;General

  ;Name and file
  Name "Custom Test"
  OutFile "custom_installer.exe"

  ;Default installation folder
  InstallDir "$LOCALAPPDATA\Custom Test"

  ;Remove default branding text of Nullsoft
  BrandingText " "

;--------------------------------
;Interface Settings
  !define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_BGCOLOR "814EFA"
  !define MUI_ABORTWARNING
  !define MUI_BGCOLOR "000000"

;--------------------------------
;Functions
Function Start
  nsDialogs::Create 1044
  Pop $0
    SetCtlColors $0 222425 FBFBFB
  
  ${NSD_CreateButton} 20 170 90% 15u INSTALL

  GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 3 ; Back Button
  GetDlgItem $1 $HWNDPARENT 1 ; Next/Close Button
  GetDlgItem $2 $HWNDPARENT 2 ; Cancel Button
  
  ShowWindow $0 ${SW_HIDE}
  ShowWindow $1 ${SW_HIDE}
  ShowWindow $2 ${SW_HIDE}

    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Pages

  Page custom Start
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

;--------------------------------
;Languages
 
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

;--------------------------------
;Installer Sections

Section "Dummy Section" SecDummy

  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

SectionEnd
```

And this is how the installer page looks like now:
[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove it on just this page or all the pages?

Comment: All the pages. Installer will only have 3 custom pages on all of which I would like to remove the bottom pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using **SetBrandingText " "** to hide the horizontal line and coloring the bottom area with **SetCtlColors $0 222425 FBFBFB** so it will look like the rest of the dialog?

Is that acceptable for you or you want to make the dialog smaller (lower its height)?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same struggle until I found this [page](https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-293979.html) which introduce WinSpy++

https://www.catch22.net/projects/winspy/

you can use this tool and mouse over the separator line to get the Control ID

in my case it is: 0xFFFFFFFF

then you can hide it like other control does:

```
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 0xFFFFFFFF
ShowWindow $0 ${SW_HIDE}
```

notice this has global effect and affect ALL nsdialog of the installer,
so you have to use ${SW_SHOW} to bring it back again in the next page preopening function